# Yosemite install

Tags: macos

How does a person obtain a copy of Yosemite when they live in a remote location and 1,000 miles by air or boat to an Apple store?  I only have Hughesnet for internet with a 350 megabyte daily restriction and can't download.  Help!!!

Answer (score 3):

You will need to contact someone who has the ability to mail you the media. Instructions for them can be found at this link:

[Create a bootable installer for OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)

You may be able to call the Applecare Support # (1-800-APL-CARE) as they may have installation media available for free or for a small fee - though I cannot guarantee that they will offer any at all.

Another option would be to contact either the closest Apple Retail Store to see if they will mail you one, or an Apple Authorized Service Provider who may also be able to mail one. A list of those can be found [here](https://locate.apple.com). Be sure to use "Service" to locate an AASP. They are licensed repair and service shops for Apple and there may be one closer to your location.

Finally, you may also find USB flashdrives with the OSX 10.10 or 10.11 installers on them via Amazon for sale, although YMMV - note that any drive purchased on a site such as Amazon may have been tampered with.